# How do SQL Server Developer Edition licenses work?

Tags: sql, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

We want to have a Development, Integration, and Production SQL Server at my company with about 20 developers having access to Development and Integration. I was wondering if the SQL Server Developer Edition can be installed on a server for the Development and Integration environment where all the developers can access it, or is Developer Edition only allowed to have one connection (meaning each developer would need it installed on their machine). If I get 20 Developer licenses, can all the developers access the same instance of the Development and Integration environments?

Also, would testers also need to have a license to the Integration environment, or is testing allowed without a license?

Answer (score 3):

SQL Developer Edition is only licensed to a single developer and can only be accessed by that one person in development activities.  No shared testing / QA / etc is allowed.  End users can access your server for acceptance testing of your product.  MS defines shared environments such as you describe as production deployments, even though they're not production for you.

See the [**licensing page for Developer**](http://www.microsoftvolumelicensing.com/userights/ProductPage.aspx?pid=325).  (Note this is for SQL 2008 R2)

For real specific questions you'll want to describe your situation to a MS sales rep.